# User Profile Self Update

Tags: forms

I want a user to come to my website and fill out the contact form depending on whether they're individual volunteer or an organization. Once they submit that form, it should create a username/password for the user so that they can visit the site and update their profile or preferences like interested in helping homeless, kids, seniors depending on whether they're individual or organization.

How do I create that form? Where do I begin? What components do I need to enable for this work?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this.

One is to use CiviCRM profiles.  There's an [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGojtcKDsCU) and a section in the [profiles documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#standalone-forms-with-profiles) on using profiles as a form.

You can also use Webform-CiviCRM integration (if on Drupal) or Caldera Forms with CiviCRM integration (if on WordPress).  These will give you more flexibility on the look and feel, and are generally more powerful - but from what you describe, you can use either.